# Radio button is invisible in android webiew. how to fix it?

Tags: android, html, webview, radio-button

I have a simple code to display a webpage in android webview

```
web=new WebView(this);
web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/rdtest.html");
```

Here it gets weird. **If I apply the below line to webview then the radio buttons are not visible in the webpage .**

```
web.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

Any Help?

My html page

```
<html>
<head>

<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;"/>
</head>
<body>

<form>
What color do you prefer?<br />
<input type="radio" name="colors" id="red" />Red<br />
<input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue" />Blue<br />
<input type="radio" name="colors" id="green" />Green
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried enableing javascript on webview?

```
web.setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean);
```

that might fix your problem.

Comment: can you try putting this html into a string and then passing that string to webview as input to check what happens? web.loadData(html, "text/html", null);

Comment: my question was that did running raw html shows you anything? do you see buttons though or buttons and radio buttons are not visible?

Comment: Only radio buttons are not visible other than that all are visible .. buttons, radio button labels, texts etc...